# How to write unsafe code blocks in c# dotnet6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want use `unsafe` block code in c#, how to enable my project to understand it?

**My Project is .Net 6**

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/language#allowunsafeblocks and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unsafe

Comment: Nothing has changed for a long time here, also note that some functionality which previously required writing unsafe code now can be achieved via `Unsafe` (and some other) classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must add this tag to your project file

[image: Project Settings]

then write code like :

```
unsafe {
     int x = 100;
     int* pinter = &x;
}
```